# Do the moving staircases move on the Marauders map?

Tags: harry-potter

Do the moving staircases move on the Marauders map in Harry Potter? and Is there a scale on the map showing how wide the staircases are?

Comment: In the film or in the novels?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123458/how-do-the-hogwarts-staircases-move-in-the-books?rq=1

Comment: @Valorum if nothing is stated isn't the unspoken convention to assume book by default?(at least for Harry Potter)